# Pipelines: Where is mavenLocal located on Pipelines?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

On [the site](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository) info is that mavenLocal is located at

> Linux/Mac: ~/.m2

But when I tried to make the command on pipelines

```
#Make publish lib to mavenLocal
./gradlew mylib:publishToMavenLocal
#Trying to zip results of publishToMavenLocal command
tar -czvf mavenLocal.tar.gz -C ~/.m2
```

Error is

```
+ tar -czvf mavenLocal.tar.gz -C ~/.m2
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```